# java directory not marked az source directory

Tags: java, maven

I build a multi module project using maven. structure of my project is like this:
[image]

In plugins/local java directory is not marked as source root. when mark it as source root and create class inside it, dependency in parent pom not recognize.

The parent pom is:

```
<groupId>my.company.inquiry</groupId>
<artifactId>InquiryManager</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>inquiry-manager-core</module>
    <module>inquiry-manager-simulator</module>
    <module>plugins/local</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The child module pom is:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>InquiryManager</artifactId>
    <groupId>my.company.inquiry</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my.company.inquiry.plugins.local</groupId>
<artifactId>local-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Right click then select "mark directory" as source.

Comment: I do this. but my dependency in parent pom not recognized

Comment: What do you see when you switch to packages mode (Currently you are in Project mode)

Comment: `local` seems to be the project directory with a `pom.xml`. `src/main/java` is the source directory (for .java), as is `src/main/resourcers` for resource files. So `src/main/java` should be marked as source directory. Normally IDEs do this automatically, certainly IntelliJ. What is a bit unusual for me, is that the module is `plugins/local`: two directory levels.

Comment: i see inquiry-manager-core & inquiry-manager-simulator & InquiryManager

Comment: move plugins/local/src to plugins/src

Comment: In Maven pane (minimized to right upper side) click "Reimport Projects" button.  Then carefully look at the messages if problem persists.

Comment: @JoopEggen Maven doesn't care about having two or more directory levels as long as the  module tag points to the directory with the pom.xml.  That pom.xml may however need to provide a relativePath tag if it has a parent.